# How to append data on a existing Json file using Java?

Tags: java, json, file

This is my current Json data in a Json file call **student.json**

```
{"name":"Mahesh","age":10}
```

I want to Append to the following data, output should be like this

```
{"name":"Mahesh","age":10}, {"name":"BROCK","age":3}, {"name":"Joe","age":4}
```

This my current code

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;  

public class JsonWritingProject
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JSONObject main = new JSONObject();

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

        try
        {
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("student.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            jsonObject.put("BROCK", 3);
            jsonObject.put("Joe", 4);
            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
        } catch (JsonIOException | JsonSyntaxException | FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



       }
```

It is not working, what should I do? Please advise

Comment: Which library you are using in your code? Where is `org.json.simple.JSONObject` from?

Comment: https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: the website you provided shows it is a python library. But your code is wriiten by Java?

Comment: doesn't matter, just to let u know the library is from that company, so anyway to write the code?

Comment: visit https://jsonlint.com/ as see that the json you require is not valid.  It looks like you need an array

Comment: Also *It is not working* is not a valid description of what is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Oh seems I forgot to post the original json file. Pls put the `student.json` with below content: (Need to wrap with `[` & `]` to make it an array)

```
[{"name":"Mahesh","age":10}]
```

Because you can not just append objects to original object, it will violate JSON syntax, the way to make it correct is to put them into an array.

### Original answer

You should change to use an array to store multiple objects. And use FileWriter to output.

Pls try this code, it works in my locl env:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.*;

public class JsonWritingProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\student.json"));
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)obj;

            System.out.println(jsonArray);

            JSONObject student1 = new JSONObject();
            student1.put("name", "BROCK");
            student1.put("age", new Integer(3));

            JSONObject student2 = new JSONObject();
            student2.put("name", "Joe");
            student2.put("age", new Integer(4));

            jsonArray.add(student1);
            jsonArray.add(student2);

            System.out.println(jsonArray);

            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\student.json");
            file.write(jsonArray.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();

        } catch (ParseException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And the library dependency is:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'
}
```

Comment: Based upon the input `{"name":"Mahesh","age":10}`  - will `JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)obj;` work?

Comment: it say Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
 at JsonWritingProject.main(JsonWritingProject.java:39)