# How could i append multiple json objects to the end of a json file

Tags: java, json

I'am currently working on a college assignment for my computer science class that involves creating a library management system in java, i had decided that i would use JSON objects to create a "book", and write it to a file. I have accomplished this with limited success though, as i'am relatively new to java (although i do have some knowledge of c).

The problem lies when the "book" is written to the file, it can only be written once; if I create another book it will override the other.

I am looking to be able to have multiple books in the file, and to be able to add books without the other books being deleted.

I saw someone with a similar question to mine that involved using JSONArrays and JSONParser, however upon testing this code I found that JSONParser no longer existed or is stored somewhere else in the json library.

I'm not sure if im allowed to post links (please just ask me to remove it if im not), but here is a link to that persons problem and the solution provided:

[How to append data on a existing Json file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402343/how-to-append-data-on-a-existing-json-file-using-java)

Here is the relevant code:
Please ask if there is anything else that would help find a solution. I may also not be able to respond straight away, but if something works or doesnt, ill let you know.

```
    // Main Stuff
    //Book creation
    JSONObject book = new JSONObject(); // make a new book using JSON
        book.put("Book title", bookname); // set book title
        book.put("Book Author", bookAuthor); // set book author
        book.put("ISBN", booknum); // set isbn

    String ReadableBooks = book.toString(); // Converts the json object to a string

       try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(bookFile)) { // creates file...
            file.write(ReadableBooks); //writes data to file
            file.flush(); // clean up after ourselves
            file.close(); // close the file stream

        } catch (IOException e) { // except if there was an error
            System.out.println("Could net create file, printing stack trace...\n");
            e.printStackTrace(); // print where the error occurred
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you want to treat `JSON` file like a database. It is not a good idea and you should use `SQL` database, [List of In-Memory Databases](https://www.baeldung.com/java-in-memory-databases) or `NOSQL`, [NoSQL Options for Java Developers](https://dzone.com/articles/nosql-options-for-java-developers). If you need only add, search, list functions you can even use `CSV` format which allow you to add new book as a new line to a file. To work with `JSON` you need to read whole file, add new book and write it back. You can of course manually work with `IO` but it sounds buggy.

Comment: If you really want to use `JSON` file to store books, try to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) library. Here you have some related questions: [Not able to java update json file using java jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810416/not-able-to-java-update-json-file-using-java-jackson), [Jackson API: partially update a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967531/jackson-api-partially-update-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, iam currently looking into the alternatives you have recommended, and can see that there are certainly better alternatives than json, namely csv seems like it would fit this very well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing your code as below snippet.

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(bookFile,true);
```

`java.io.FileWriter` provides a method as bellow.

```
public FileWriter(@NotNull java.io.File file,
                      boolean append) throws java.io.IOException
```

As you can see in the java docs, `Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.`
**Params:**
    file – a File object to write to
    append – if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning